# Merging django url patterns with numeric id or name

Tags: django, http, rest

I'm implementing a web service (no html, no templates, just JSON) with django and i'd like to be able to merge some url patterns code so it doesn't repeat itself.

This are the urls that need to be supported:

```
host/players/12/  this returns the player's  12  info
host/players/me/  this returns the logged player info
```

The two return the same if the logged player has id 12.
I also need to support more urls like:

```
host/players/12/other-stuff/
host/players/me/other-stuff/
```

How could i avoid having two different view methods for /other-stuff/?

This what I have so far:

```
instance_url_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',            instance_with_id),
    url(r'^other_stuff$', other_stuff_with_id),
    # more suff goes in here
)

current_instance_url_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',            instance_without_id),
    url(r'^other_stuff$', other_stuff_without_id),
    # more suff goes in here
)

players_url_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',           show_list),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)', include(instance_url_patterns)),
    url(r'^me/$',        include(current_instance_url_patterns)),
)


# This is the origin of all the above urls (located in urls.py)
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^players/',       include(players.relation_url_patterns)),
)
```

Notice how i need to have all urls twice in instance_url_patterns and current_instance_url_patterns and also their methods for their implementations.

Is there any way to merge/improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid duplicating view functions, use a single view function with a default value of `None` for `pk`, and bind it to the logged in user's `pk` if it's `None`.  See the example in the [url dispatcher docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#notes-on-capturing-text-in-urls)

Assuming your players are instances of the default auth's `user` model, a simplified version would look something like this:

```
views.py
def player_info(request, pk=None):
    if pk is None:
        player = request.user
    else:
        player = get_object_or_404(user, pk=int(pk))
    # now do stuff with the player

urls.py
players_url_patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',           show_list),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', player_info),
    url(r'^me/$',        player_info),
)
```

You have to specify all the patterns that you want to bind to a view, but you don't need two different views just to default to the current user if no one else is specified.

Comment: I assume that, in my case, both would include the same patterns, right? I'll mark the answer as accepted a bit latter (to see if there are more answers)

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to declare your `other_stuff` URLs as well.  In theory I believe you could collapse the regexps for the `pk` and `me` cases into a single line - `r'^(?:(?P<pk>\d+)|me)/$'` - but I usually find that I want to give the default case a different name for later reverse lookup anyway.